# Positioning SVG Elements

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

In the course of toying with SVG for the first time (using the [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html) library), I've run into a problem positioning dynamic elements on the canvas in such a way that they're *completely* contained within the canvas. What I'm trying to do is randomly position *n* words/short phrases.

Since the text is variable, its position needs to be variable as well so what I'm doing is:

1. Initially creating the text at point `0,0` with no opacity.
2. Checking the width of the drawn text element using `text.getBBox().width`.
3. Setting a new `x` coordinate as `Math.random() * (canvas_width - ( text_width/2 ) - pad)`.
4. Altering the `x` coordinate of the text to the newly set value (`text.attr( 'x', x )` ).
5. Setting the opacity attribute of the text to 1.

I'll be the first to admit that my math acumen is limited, but this seems pretty straightforward. Somehow, I still end up with text running off beyond the right edge of my canvas. For simplicity above, I removed the bit that also sets a minimum `x` value by adding it to the `Math.random()` result. It is there, though, and I see the same problem on the leading edge of the canvas.

My understanding (such as it is), is that the `Math.random()` bits would generate a number between 0 and 1 which could then be multiplied by some number (in my case, the canvas width - half of the text width - some arbitrary padding) to get the outer bound. I'm dividing the width of the text in half because its position on the grid is set at its center.

I hope I've just been staring at this for too long, but is my math *that* rusty or am I misunderstanding something about the behavior of `Math.random()`, SVG, text or anything else that's under the hood of this solution?

Comment: Sorry - I thought I had a solution so I deleted/undeleted, but then realized the math worked out to what you had before.  I don't know what Raphael is doing under the covers so I can't really help you.

Comment: No problem. You may have been on the right track, though. Looking more closely at how `Math.random()` operated and the division by 2 may have been the culprit after all. Will follow up if that works out to be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be how I was thinking about the `Math.random()` equation. It's not quite as simple as multiplying by the max and then adding the minimum value (of course). It's really more like establishing a double wide gutter on the right end of the container and then shifting the entire boundary to eat up half of that gutter:

```
var x  = Math.random() * ( canvas_w - 20 - ( text.getBBox().width ) ) + ( text.getBBox().width/2 + 10 );
```

In English...

You have to double the width of each element you want to account for so you can shift the entire range back by that width to keep things nice and equal. In my case, I want to account for half of the width of the text plus a padding of 10.

For example...

Given a canvas width of `500`, a text width of `50` and a desired "gutter" of `10`, I create a random number between `0` and `430` (`500 - 20 - 50`). By adding back the widths I need to account for--half of the text width (`25`) + the padding (`10`)--I'm left with a random number between `35` and `465`. If my text sits at the outer edges of that boundary, it can only reach as far as the `10` or `490`.

Hopefully that's clear enough to make sense. Although it makes sense when I think about it, this kind of thing isn't immediately intuitive to me, so I'm sure I'll be referring back here often.